# Navbar hides initial content when jumping to in-page anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to prevent navbar from overlapping initial content of Website. I've used bootstrap navbar and while moving one page to the particular section on another page using thumbnail anchor tag. Navbar is overlapping initial content.

```js
<script>
 var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50) };
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
    function load() { if (window.location.hash) shiftWindow(); } 
</script>
```

```html
<li>
<a target="_blank" href="service.html#family">
     <figure class="service-img5"><h4 class="link-caption">family                     offices</h4></figure>
 </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a target="_blank" href="service.html#fund">
     <figure class="service-img5"><h4 class="link-caption">fund                     syndication</h4></figure>
 </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you put some example code ?

Comment: yes sure @bruce182

Comment: Put the code that produces the minimum out to see your problem, that doesn nothing at all what you've posted.